# Chess Checkmate Algorithm Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, graph-algorithm

I was wondering what the complexity of a graph search algorithm would be for determining a checkmate in chess in Big O notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the algorithm would solve all the possible moves by the remaining chess pieces (N). Since it only goes through each piece once the complexity is O(N) (Linear).

Answer (score 2):

8 pieces on each side. First move has 16 possibilities for just the pawns alone and another 4 for the knights, second movie has the same amount. After this the list of possibilities grow to an uncomputable level.

The best chess engines in the world use 'most probable' graph searches.

This wikipedia article is very useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity

"Allis also estimated the game-tree complexity to be at least 10123, "based on an average branching factor of 35 and an average game length of 80". As a comparison, the number of atoms in the observable universe, to which it is often compared, is estimated to be between 4×1079 and 1081."

Answer (score 0):

The king has at most eight moves. And it takes constant time to verify if a king is threatened after each move. Plus the case where king stay put (and another piece moves). So it's constant time.

Comment: Does that mean O(1)? Wouldn't it vary by how many pieces remained on the board?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a given board contains a checkmate, then you could do something like this:

1. determine the (king)set of squares your king could move to (8 in all directions - fields occupied by your own pieces - borders of field)
2. iterate over all enemy pieces and determine the squares they attack. If any of those squares are in your kingset, remove them. Maintain a boolean to indicate if your king is under attack.
3. checkmate if your kingset gets empty and the king is under attack

The number of pieces does play a role, so if you have an arbitrary sized board with n pieces, it does matter. In that case, the bottleneck will be to check for all pieces if they attack a position or not because another piece could block the attack. A simple implementation could do it in quadratic time.
By maintaining the positions of the pieces in a set and optimise it for add() and contains() you could get this down to linear in n (although the size of the board will also influence this) so I guess linear complexity is feasible.